# Error: Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\Postgre\Connection::select()

Tags: codeigniter-4

```
public function getLoad() {
        $q = $this->conn->select('load.level_id, load.section_id, sub.subject_title, sub.subject_name')
        ->from('academics.tbl_teaching_load load')
        ->join('academics.tbl_subjects sub', 'sub.subject_id = load.subject_id')
        ->where('user_id', $this->request->getVar('user_id'))
        ->get()->getResult();
        echo json_encode($q);
    }
```

As the title said, it returns an error: Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\Postgre\Connection::select()

I am new too CI4 and trying to join a table. The only problem I encounter so far is this. I can't seem to find the solution for the problem. Any help or tips will do. TYIA

Comment: Can you post the entire model you're using to do this query?

Comment: What does `$this->conn` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

##### Error:

```bash
Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\\Database\\Postgre\\Connection::select()
```

##### Explanation:

The error above is pretty clear. You're trying to call the `select(...)` method which ***doesn't*** exist in the [`CodeIgniter\Database\Postgre\Connection`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c0b9928bc7dc983f7914f379795197ee7410db1a/system/Database/Postgre/Connection.php#L22) class.

However, the `select(...)` method *exists* in the [`CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c0b9928bc7dc983f7914f379795197ee7410db1a/system/Database/BaseBuilder.php#L26) class. You can receive the `BaseBuilder` instance from the `Connection` instance through the inherited [`CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection::table(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c0b9928bc7dc983f7914f379795197ee7410db1a/system/Database/BaseConnection.php#L869) method.

In addition, I would recommend you to first `join` your table(s) *before* selecting columns using the `->select(...)` method. That would be easier to read and interpret.

Hence, reorder and change your query to...

##### Solution:

```php
public function getLoad()
{
    $q = $this->conn->table('academics.tbl_teaching_load load')
        ->join('academics.tbl_subjects sub', 'sub.subject_id = load.subject_id')
        ->where('user_id', $this->request->getVar('user_id'))
        ->select(['load.level_id', 'load.section_id', 'sub.subject_title', 'sub.subject_name'])
        ->get()->getResult();
    echo json_encode($q);
}
```